# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Exception while running birt 4.3.1 report in Tomcat in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: birt

For the last year I have been using Birt 4.2.2 connected to PostgreSQL 9.1 in Eclipse Juno in Windows 7 with Tomcat 7 without any problems and it was running fine. But, I have created a new Birt Project in a MacBookPro with Eclipse Kepler and Birt 4.3.1 and when I run a report by Java Code when the project is deployed in Tomcat 7 the following exception is shown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/datatools/enablement/ibm/util/ClientUtil 
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.DB2LUWDriverValuesProvider.locateDB2DriverJars(DB2LUWDriverValuesProvider.java:38)
```

However, if I run the report in preview mode works OK and if I import my old projects with Birt 4.2.2, all reports run OK as well.

Why this is happening? Why is shown in the Exception an access to DB2 Driver if I am using PostgreSQL?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a classforname somewhere in your DOA code with the db2 driver specified?

Comment: No, I use a connection profile where only I specify the Postgres Driver. It´s so weird because the same code with the same report and the same connection profile is working in another project in the same eclipe but with birt 4.2.2